# Stop narrator from switching on automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows, narrator

From  the time I started using my computer, Narrator has automatically been turning on when I switch on the computer or run an application which requests admin rights.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium, and wish to stop Narrator as its very annoying.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open **Control Panel**, go to **Ease of Access** - **Ease of Access Center**. Then select **Make computer easier to use**.

Go to **Use computer without a display** and uncheck **Turn on Narrator**. Don't forget the **Apply** button at the bottom of the page.

[image]

Comment: @Comelius Thank you for your answer. I will duly mark it. Before you answered, I just renamed narrator.exe as narrator.exe.bak, but the check box for narrator was highlighted and that was what was causing the problem.